# How do I pass the find command to the bash script as a argument?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, find, arguments

This command is a command to find hidden files.

The command is well recognized when executed at terminal.

However, if you turn the command over to the argument in the bash script, it will be recognized as an invalid command.

If you write \ together to recognize special characters, the results will not be printed.

I want to execute the command by passing the find command to the argument value of the bash script.

What should I do?

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**<test.sh>**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n $1 ]
then
    echo $@
    command=`$@`
    echo $command
fi
```

**<terminal>**

```
[root@localhost ~]# find / -xdev -name '.*'
/usr/lib/debug/usr/.dwz
/usr/lib64/.libgcrypt.so.11.hmac
/usr/lib64/.libcrypto.so.1.0.2k.hmac
/usr/lib64/.libcrypto.so.10.hmac
/usr/lib64/.libssl.so.1.0.2k.hmac
/usr/lib64/.libssl.so.10.hmac
/usr/share/man/man1/..1.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/.k5identity.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/.k5login.5.gz
/usr/share/kde4/apps/kdm/themes/CentOS7/.colorlsCZ1
/home/test01/.bash_logout
/home/test01/.bash_profile
/home/test01/.bashrc
/home/test01/.bash_history
/home/test02/.bash_logout
/home/test02/.bash_profile
/home/test02/.bashrc
/home/test02/.bash_history
```

**<execute test.sh script >**

```
[root@localhost ~]# ./test.sh find / -xdev -name '.*'
find / -xdev -name . ..
find: pahts must precede expression: ..
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]


[root@localhost ~]# ./test.sh find / -xdev -name \'.*\'
find / -xdev -name '.*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `eval` instead

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -n $1 ]
then
    echo $@
    command=$@
    eval $command
fi
```

```
[ linux ]$ ./test.sh find /tmp/ -xdev -name \".*\"
find /tmp/ -xdev -name ".*"
/tmp/.hidden2
/tmp/.hidden1
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `*` so it's not evaluated by the shell

```
./test.sh find / -xdev -name '.\*'
```

Also, use https://www.shellcheck.net/ for other improvements.